# Axios post unauthorized error yet curl works

Tags: rest, axios, youtrack, youtrack-api

Trying to hit YouTrack's API via axios but I am receiving an unauthorized error, while same params via curl work.

curl:

```
curl -X GET \
'https://<my youtrack url>/api/issues' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer perm:<my token>' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

axios:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer perm:<my token>'
    },
    responseType: 'json',
};

axios.get('https://<my youtrack url>/api/issues', {}, config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error: ', e.response.data)
    });
```

The curl correctly returns JSON of my available issues, whereas my axios call returns an error

```
{error: "Unauthorized", error_description: ""}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send the config as the second parameter, as GET requests don't need the body

```
axios.get('https://<my youtrack url>/api/issues', config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error: ', e.response.data)
    });
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. The code snippet from auth0 used `axios.request`; i changed this to an `axios.post` and it worked as expected.